# IntelliJ: shortcuts for comments do not work anymore on html files

Tags: intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ ultimate editions, shortcuts for comments do not work anymore on html files (and just on html files). It happened suddenly after a restart (I had maybe install a plugin, but I'm not sure).

I just updated to the last version (173.4548.28), but the problem persists.

In the settings I don't find anything defining in which types of file the shortcuts are available.

Where should I look to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to invalidate all caches? You can find this under *File*.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately without any result.

Comment: Dos it work via Main menu | Code | Comment with Line Comment action? In Settings(Preferences) | Plugins disable all **Custom** plugins. Check what shortcut do you see when search by "Comment with Line Comment". Also make sure that html files are indeed detected as html files (File | Settings | Editor | File Types check the registered patterns for the HTML there).

Comment: The problem was indeed that *.html files were not recognized as html file. Thank you for your comment, post it as an answer and I will accept it.